# Knit is not working properly compared to running the chunk

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

When knitting the markdown document, the following chunk produces only NA's into the `s` data frame, but running the chunk independently works as expected. All the necessary data.frames that are called for in the lmer() functions were created earlier in the markdown document. I think it might be something with the get() function, but do not understand why it would work with running the chunk but not while knitting.

```r
s=data.frame(row.names = c("ss_on","ss_off","nonss_on","nonss_off","log_draws","log_length","ss_on_co2"),
             var_names=c("ss_on_","ss_off_","nonss_on_","nonss_off_","log_draws_","log_length_","ss_on_co2_"),
             log_twh=c(T,T,F,T,F,T,F),
             log_swh=c(T,T,T,T,T,F,F),
             twh = "",twh_uci = "",twh_lci = "",swh="",swh_uci="",swh_lci="")

for(i in which(s$log_twh==F)){
  lmer.fit <- lmer(y ~  (1| Location) , data=get(paste0(s$var_names[i],"twh")))
  t=summary(lmer.fit)
  s$twh[i]=t$coefficients[1]
  s$twh_uci[i]=t$coefficients[1]+as.data.frame(t$varcor)$sdcor[1]
  s$twh_lci[i]=t$coefficients[1]-as.data.frame(t$varcor)$sdcor[1]
}
for(i in which(s$log_swh==F)){
  lmer.fit <- lmer(y ~  (1| Location) , data=get(paste0(s$var_names[i],"swh")))
  t=summary(lmer.fit)
  s$swh[i]=t$coefficients[1]
  s$swh_uci[i]=t$coefficients[1]+as.data.frame(t$varcor)$sdcor[1]
  s$swh_lci[i]=t$coefficients[1]-as.data.frame(t$varcor)$sdcor[1]
}

for(i in which(s$log_twh==T)){
  lmer.fit <- lmer(log(y) ~  (1| Location) , data=get(paste0(s$var_names[i],"twh")))
  t=summary(lmer.fit)
  s$twh[i]=exp(t$coefficients[1])
  s$twh_uci[i]=exp(t$coefficients[1]+as.data.frame(t$varcor)$sdcor[1])
  s$twh_lci[i]=exp(t$coefficients[1]-as.data.frame(t$varcor)$sdcor[1])
}

for(i in which(s$log_swh==T)){
  lmer.fit <- lmer(log(y) ~  (1| Location) , data=get(paste0(s$var_names[i],"swh")))
  t=summary(lmer.fit)
  s$swh[i]=exp(t$coefficients[1])
  s$swh_uci[i]=exp(t$coefficients[1]+as.data.frame(t$varcor)$sdcor[1])
  s$swh_lci[i]=exp(t$coefficients[1]-as.data.frame(t$varcor)$sdcor[1])
}
print(s)
```

All of the values inserted into data frame `s` are NA's when knitting, but work properly when running the chunk.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your environment is clean. Running the code you provided throws several errors (see below).

This seems to be the most common cause of code running as expected in the console or chunk by chunk but failing when knitting.

```r
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
s=data.frame(row.names = c("ss_on","ss_off","nonss_on","nonss_off","log_draws","log_length","ss_on_co2"),
             var_names=c("ss_on_","ss_off_","nonss_on_","nonss_off_","log_draws_","log_length_","ss_on_co2_"),
             log_twh=c(T,T,F,T,F,T,F),
             log_swh=c(T,T,T,T,T,F,F),
             twh = "",twh_uci = "",twh_lci = "",swh="",swh_uci="",swh_lci="")

for(i in which(s$log_twh==F)){
  lmer.fit <- lmer(y ~  (1| Location) , data=get(paste0(s$var_names[i],"twh")))
  t=summary(lmer.fit)
  s$twh[i]=t$coefficients[1]
  s$twh_uci[i]=t$coefficients[1]+as.data.frame(t$varcor)$sdcor[1]
  s$twh_lci[i]=t$coefficients[1]-as.data.frame(t$varcor)$sdcor[1]
}
#> Error in checkFormulaData(formula, data, checkLHS = control$check.formula.LHS == : bad 'data': object 'nonss_on_twh' not found
for(i in which(s$log_swh==F)){
  lmer.fit <- lmer(y ~  (1| Location) , data=get(paste0(s$var_names[i],"swh")))
  t=summary(lmer.fit)
  s$swh[i]=t$coefficients[1]
  s$swh_uci[i]=t$coefficients[1]+as.data.frame(t$varcor)$sdcor[1]
  s$swh_lci[i]=t$coefficients[1]-as.data.frame(t$varcor)$sdcor[1]
}
#> Error in checkFormulaData(formula, data, checkLHS = control$check.formula.LHS == : bad 'data': object 'log_length_swh' not found

for(i in which(s$log_twh==T)){
  lmer.fit <- lmer(log(y) ~  (1| Location) , data=get(paste0(s$var_names[i],"twh")))
  t=summary(lmer.fit)
  s$twh[i]=exp(t$coefficients[1])
  s$twh_uci[i]=exp(t$coefficients[1]+as.data.frame(t$varcor)$sdcor[1])
  s$twh_lci[i]=exp(t$coefficients[1]-as.data.frame(t$varcor)$sdcor[1])
}
#> Error in checkFormulaData(formula, data, checkLHS = control$check.formula.LHS == : bad 'data': object 'ss_on_twh' not found

for(i in which(s$log_swh==T)){
  lmer.fit <- lmer(log(y) ~  (1| Location) , data=get(paste0(s$var_names[i],"swh")))
  t=summary(lmer.fit)
  s$swh[i]=exp(t$coefficients[1])
  s$swh_uci[i]=exp(t$coefficients[1]+as.data.frame(t$varcor)$sdcor[1])
  s$swh_lci[i]=exp(t$coefficients[1]-as.data.frame(t$varcor)$sdcor[1])
}
#> Error in checkFormulaData(formula, data, checkLHS = control$check.formula.LHS == : bad 'data': object 'ss_on_swh' not found
print(s)
#>              var_names log_twh log_swh twh twh_uci twh_lci swh swh_uci
#> ss_on           ss_on_    TRUE    TRUE                                
#> ss_off         ss_off_    TRUE    TRUE                                
#> nonss_on     nonss_on_   FALSE    TRUE                                
#> nonss_off   nonss_off_    TRUE    TRUE                                
#> log_draws   log_draws_   FALSE    TRUE                                
#> log_length log_length_    TRUE   FALSE                                
#> ss_on_co2   ss_on_co2_   FALSE   FALSE                                
#>            swh_lci
#> ss_on             
#> ss_off            
#> nonss_on          
#> nonss_off         
#> log_draws         
#> log_length        
#> ss_on_co2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the reply - the errors you got appear to be because lmer() can't find the data.frame, but they are all created in previous chunks in the script. I just tried clearing the global environment and running all previous chunks, and this chunk works as expected when run separately, but produces NA's when it is knit.

Comment: It would help if you provided a fully reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to send the necessary data frames that you would need to reproduce this error. As the code shows, you would need 14 different data frames in order for it to work properly. If you have any ideas, I'm open to hearing them. Thanks!